# How to remove empty/blank space while retrieving a value from an input file in unix

Tags: unix

I'm writing a script in which I need to retrieve input parameters for the script from a text file. There are around 10 such input parameters to be retrieved. The input file is actually retrieved from a tool with customer details in description, hence it comes in any format. Sometimes there comes an empty space or blank space after or before the title.

```
For example: 
Consider the customer details as below
Name: Divya 
Email: divyaapinky@gmail.com
```

And I'm doing the below in my script

```
name=`grep -i name input_file.txt | awk -F":" '{print $2}'`
echo $name
```

The above gives me the name with a space " Divya"

The above has some space in after the colon, so when I'm trying to retrieve the name or email address, it's giving space as well. Please note, that I have to use colon only as delimiter and not space as not every field has space, it depends on how customer provides the details.

Could you please suggest me a command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sed` command to get your desired output. Please find below the command which might help you.

```
sed s/^ *//g
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it seems to work. Let me apply the same for all the fields and will get back in case of any issues.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the sed command for all the fields (total 10 in my script). However it seems to work fine for some fields and not for others. Unable to identify the reason for the same. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I see the `grep` a bit problematic: what happens if 'name' is part of the email address? A better solution would be:

```
INPUTFILE="input_file.txt"
NAME=`grep -i "^name:" "${INPUTFILE}" | sed 's/^name:[ \t]*//; s/[ \t]*$//'`
echo "${NAME}"
```

That greps "name:" only at the beginning of a line and eliminates leading and trailing spaces and tabs.